# Best Practices with IF statement in Catch block

Tags: c#, exception, design-patterns

I have a method like the following:

```
public static addSomething(int id)
{
    string msg = getStringMsg(id);
    try
    {
        //do lots of stuff
        Console.WriteLine(msg)
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (id == 1)
            throw new Exception("Exception msg 1: " + msg);
        else
            throw new Exception("Exception msg 2: " + msg);
    }
}
```

Is having a conditional branch like this in the catch block frowned upon? If so, what are my alternatives?

I guess I can do:

```
public static addSomething(int id)
{
    string msg = getStringMsg(id);
    string exceptionMsg;
    if (id == 1)
        exceptionMsg = "Exception msg 1: " + msg);
    else
        exceptionMsg = "Exception msg 2: " + msg);
    try
    {
        //do lots of stuff
        Console.WriteLine(msg)
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(exceptionMsg);
    }
}
```

But I would really like to keep the code outside of the try block to a minimum, if at all. Which comes to my second question: is there a way I can assign `getStringMsg(id)` to `msg` inside of the `try` block, yet still have access to it in the `catch` block?

Comment: For code readability, I would personally go with your first example. The question I have is why you wouldn't just take e.Message, msg, and id, format it to your needs and then bubble it up. Generally catch blocks are to recover the application, not for business logic.

Comment: One more question - do you really need to add `msg` returned by `getStringMsg(id)` to error message? And what do you need in your *lots of stuff* part - `msg` or `id`, or both of them?

Comment: Answer to first question is yes. This is a very simplified version to get at the core of the problem. And yes, I need `msg` and `id` in `//lots of stuff`.

Comment: I've seen you post a few questions. After reading them, I really thing you should concider creating a class instead of passing the ID. There seem to be a lot of different functionality depending on the ID, this should be stored in a centralized place.

Comment: @the_lotus: I completely agree with you, but unfortunately that design decision is not up to me.

Comment: @mattm ah! I understand. Maybe you could fix your string problems by using resources. You could have something like GetStringResource("error_message_" + id)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you avoiding error message creation until error occurs. Also I suggest to pass original exception as inner exception to exception you are throwing (and it's better to create some custom exception if you are plaining to throw it to higher levels of your application):

```
public static void addSomething(int id)
{
    string msg = getStringMsg(id);
    try
    {
        //do lots of stuff
        Console.WriteLine(msg)
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string errorMessage = (id == 1) ? 
           "Exception msg 1: " : "Exception msg 2: ";

        throw new FooException(errorMessage + msg, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe your `try` block also has lot of `conditional logic` based on your parameter `id`. In that case, **it would be good to split the implementation in separate methods**, each with its own `try catch` block.

Also consider the refactoring - [replace conditional with polymorphism](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's fine, but you should pass the thrown exception as the inner exception of what you throw:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
      throw new Exception("message", ex);
    ...
}
```

If you ever want to rethrow the handle exception, just type `throw;`. Do not throw it again. There's lots of articles on the difference and why a single word statement - `throw` - is best.